# Why updating list template to require a field affects list that were created using older template?

Tags: 2013

Scenario : I created 100 lists using a custom list template I created and there custom field address was left "**NOT REQUIRED**"

I updated solution in Visual Studio 2013 and update field to be **REQUIRED** and now it should only make this field required for future lists created using this template.

At least this is how it used to happen in SharePoint 2007, anything changed between 2007 and 2013 ???

Comment: When you say you updated the field. How, was that within the list schema?

Comment: If your list template uses a custom site content type, then Visual Studio will push changes to the content type, which, in turns, will push changes to all lists inheriting from it

Comment: Nope nothing to do with content type, i just created a custom list template using visual studio provided templates, i also deployed wsp using powershell to another server and same results.